# std::sort with equal elements gives Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault

I have a container storing pointers. I am trying to sort these pointers in non-increasing order based on a data member in the corresponding objects pointed by the pointers. In my case, it is possible that many objects have the same value for that data member.

The following is a short code to illustrate the problem. The call to the sort function is giving a Segmentation fault. The weird thing about this is, if I have 16 elements in the container pointing to objects with same value for the double, the sort seems to work. But if I have 17 elements pointing to objects with same value, it gives a seg fault.

Can anyone please explain why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>

//some class
class A {
public:
    double a;
    A(double aval);
};

A::A(double aval) : a(aval) {}

//compare class
struct cmp_A : std::greater_equal<A*> {
    bool operator() (const A* x, const A* y) const;
} cmp_A_obj;

//greater_equal comparison
bool cmp_A::operator() (const A* x, const A* y) const {
    return (x->a >= y->a);
}

int main() {
    std::deque<A*> Adeque;
    //insert 17 A pointers into the container
    for(int i = 1; i<=17; i++) {
        Adeque.push_back(new A(5));
    }

    //This call to sort gives a Segmentation fault
    std::sort(Adeque.begin(), Adeque.end(), cmp_A_obj);

    for(std::deque<A*>::iterator i = Adeque.begin(); i!= Adeque.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << "|" << (*i)->a;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your comparison must implement a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). Less than or equal does not satisfy this. It should be equivalent to "less than" or "greater than" as implemented in operators `<` and `>` for, say, integers.

Equality of elements is determined by applying this ordering twice:

```
(!cmp(a,b)) && (!cmp(b,a)); // if this is false, a == b
```

Comment: You should probably change "less than or greater than" to "`<` or `>`" to be less ambiguous. (less than or greater than can be interpreted as `!=`)

Comment: @Pubby I rephrased that part of the answer. I was worried that my answer would imply that one has to overload `<` or `>`.

Comment: +10 This is such a huge trap for the unwary. I've been bitten by this bug myself, and it's really not obvious what is causing the problem. IMHO it needs to be better documented in all the STL references.